# Consulta AJAX Duda sobre warning del navegador

Tags: php, ajax

hola amigos tengo una duda como veran trabajo con php javascript jquery etc..
mi inquietud es la siguiente a la hora de yo hacer una llamada **ajax** en la misma llamada agrego una etiqueta de script por que de verdad la necesito para ejecutar las funciones correspondientes una ves que **ajax** me devuelva el **data**, pero el navegador me muestra un warning como veran en la imagen debajo. queria saver si hay una forma mas eficiente de incluir etiquetas de script el las llamadas aqui les dejo un ejemplo con **codigo**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque me arroje este **warning** el codigo me funciona a la perfeccion pero la verdad que me inquieta quiero que mi codigo quede lo mas limpio posible

y este es mi codigo de la llamada **ajax**

```
//en este div se mostraran los chats
<div id="chat-here"></div>
/*Aqui el cuelpo del formulario que necesito traer*/
    <div id='next'>



     <?php 
        $selector=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM registro");
        while($usuarios=mysqli_fetch_array($selector)){

        $messages= mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM mensajes WHERE de='$yo' AND 
         para='$id' AND status=0");
        $message_cuantily=mysqli_num_rows($messages); ?>

        <div id='roome' style='width:100%;  position:fixed;  height:55px;  bottom:85px; background:white; padding:3px; background:white; margin-left:-15;'>

        //nesecito traer este formulario que luego llamara otro archivo como veran
        //para que me inserte los mensajes
           <form action='insertar_mensajes.php' method='get' class='formi' 
             id='formi'>

           <div class='input-group' >
           <div class='input-group-append' >

           <input type="text" placeholder="escribe tu mensaje" id="justchat" 
        class="chatting" name="textoChat" >
           <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo$message_cuantily?>' 
             name='message_ca' id='message_ca'>
             //mediante unos input hidden enviare alguna informacion
           <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $myfoto?>' name='fot' id='fot'>
           <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo$id?>' name='dato' id='dato'>
            <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo$yo?>' name='yo' id='yo'>

           <button type='submit' class='btn btn-outline-dark intro' id='<?php echo$usuarios["id"]?>'>Enviar</button>
           </div>
           </form>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>


        /*en esta misma llamada ajax necesito agregar esta etiqueta de script*/
     /*si no la agrego no me funciona el formulario*/ 
        <script src="js/Clientes.js"></script>
```

** mi ajax**

```
url="message.php";

      $.ajax({

        url:url,
        type:"GET",
        data:{id:id}, 
        success:function(response){

         $("#mensajes").fadeIn("fast");
         $("#message_notifications").fadeOut("fast");
         $("#shower").fadeOut("fast");
         $("#cuerpo").html(data);//aqui se muestra mi formulario

        }



         })
```

este mi simple codigo no quise dar un ejemplo tan largo para no ostigarlos muchos chicos NOTA: no es que el codigo no me funcione al contrario me funciona a la perfeccion pero el **warning** del navegador me inquieta  XD agradeceria cualquier consejo y que tan malo es esto o si solo devo ignorar este **warning**

Comment: Prueba a escribir la petición Ajax así: `var url="message.php";
 
 var myAjax = 
  $.ajax(
     {
      url: url,
      method: 'GET',
      data: {id:id}
     }
    );

 myAjax.done(
     function(response) 
     {
      $("#mensajes").fadeIn("fast");
      $("#message_notifications").fadeOut("fast");
      $("#shower").fadeOut("fast");
      $("#cuerpo").html(response);//aqui se muestra mi formulario       
     }
    );
  
 myAjax.fail(
     function(jqXHR, textStatus) 
     {
      alert("Hubo un error: " + textStatus);
     }
    );`

Comment: lo hice pero no funciono osea funciona el codigo pero me arroja el mismo warning gracias como quiera por tu intencion

Comment: Prueba a cambiar tu librería de jQuery, quita la que tengas y pon esta que es la última versión estable: **`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`**

Comment: ya que lo mencionas tengo la libreria 1.7 de jquery, ahora que bueno que lo mencionas tengo la version 1.7 por que si la actualiso a la ultima me da un error que no puedo entender todo lo que funciona con click me lo ocualta no entiendo por que razon en la consola me dice indexof is not a function

Comment: La versión `1.7`... y resulta que jQuery está en su versión `3`... como podrás entender hay que ir pensando en actualizar el código. Puedes crear una prueba nada más con la petición Ajax, usando el código de mi anterior respuesta y jQuery 3. No debería haber razón para que siga dando ese warning. Si desparace con esa prueba quedará claro que lo mejor es actualizar  a jQuery 3 y luego ir corrigiendo/actualizando el otro código (posiblemente muy viejo) que no funciona. El warning que tienes ahora parece ser un bug corregido en las nuevas versiones de jQuery.

Comment: vale como se solucionaria ese problema  creeme intente varias semanas atras actualizar el jquery 3 y me da un error fatal todo lo que funciona con un click en mi pagina desaparese no entiendo pero si pongo la version 1.7 todo normal ecepto por el warning

Comment: Tendrías que comparar tu sintaxis (antigua) con la sintaxis [explicada en la doc de jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/click/)  en el caso concreto de click, si es eso lo que falla. jQuery 3 creo que tiene un plugin para ayudarte a [actualizar/migrar el código](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#jquery-core-3-0-upgrade-guide). Pero esto es ya otro asunto.